how to change the colors of ant chart design's colorField property
I have the following code in nextjs,
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { Column } from '@ant-design/plots';

const ColumnChart = ({ data }: any) => {
  const config = {
    data,
    xField: 'mounth',
    yField: 'total',
    colorField: 'mounth',
    color: ['#9a261d', '#b02b21', '#c53126'],
    style: {
      radiusTopLeft: 10,
      radiusTopRight: 10,
    },
  };
  return <Column {...config} />;
};

export default ColumnChart;

I am trying to change color to the columns, if in colorField instead of month I put some color, it changes to that color, but if I leave it as it is, the ant itself use some default colors it has, how do I change or replace those default colors.
I attach image


I recently encountered the same issue and found a solution. Instead of using color:, try the following approach:
scale: { 
  color: { 
    range: ['#9a261d', '#b02b21', '#c53126'] 
  } 
},

This should apply the correct color range as intended.
